# Cassandra Write getting slow in heavy writes - Load Factor surges up on one machine in the cluster

Tags: performance, cassandra

We are using cassandra 3.0.3 on AWS with 6 r3.xlarge machines (64G RAM, 16 Core) each, there are 6 machines in 2 datacenter's but this particular keyspace is replicated in only one DC therefore on 3 Nodes. We are writing about 300M rows into cassandra as a weekly sync.

During loading data **load factor shooting up to as much as 34** on a machine and 100% CPU utilization (In this case a lot of data will be rewritten), we expected it to be slow but the performance degradation is dramatic on one of the nodes.

At a snapshot, load factor output for the machines:

```
On Overloaded Machine:
27.47, 29.78, 30.06

On other two:
2.65, 3.95, 4.59
3.76, 2.52, 2.50
```

`nodetool status` output:

```
Overloaded Node:
UN  10.21.56.21    65.94 GB   256          38.7%             57f35206-f264-44ec-b588-f72883139f69  rack1

Other two Nodes:
UN  10.21.56.20    56.34 GB   256          31.9%             2b29f85c-c783-4e20-8cea-95d4e2688550  rack1
UN  10.21.56.23    51.29 GB   256          29.4%             fbf26f1d-1766-4f12-957c-7278fd19c20c  rack1
```

I can see that the sstable count is also high and sstable flushed are ~15MB in size. Heap size is 8GB and G1GC is used.

The output of `nodetool cfhistograms` shows stark difference between write and read latency as can be shown below for one of the larger tables:

```
| Percentile    |  SSTables     |  Write Latency    |  Read Latency     |  Partition Size   |  Cell Count   |
|-------------  |------------   |-----------------  |----------------   |------------------ |-------------- |
|               |  (micros)     |  (micros)         |  (bytes)          |                   |               |
| 50%           | 8             | 20.5              | 1629.72           | 179               | 5             |
| 75%           | 10            | 24.6              | 2346.8            | 258               | 10            |
| 95%           | 12            | 42.51             | 4866.32           | 1109              | 72            |
| 98%           | 14            | 51.01             | 10090.81          | 3973              | 258           |
| 99%           | 14            | 61.21             | 14530.76          | 9887              | 642           |
| Min           | 0             | 4.77              | 11.87             | 104               | 5             |
| Max           | 17            | 322381.14         | 17797419.59       | 557074610         | 36157190      |
```

`nodetool proxyhistogram` output can be found below:

```
Percentile      Read Latency     Write Latency     Range Latency
                    (micros)          (micros)          (micros)
50%                   263.21            654.95          20924.30
75%                   654.95            785.94          30130.99
95%                  1629.72          36157.19          52066.35
98%                  4866.32         155469.30          62479.63
99%                  7007.51         322381.14          74975.55
Min                     6.87             11.87             24.60
Max              12359319.16       30753941.06       63771372.18
```

One wierd thing that I can observe here is that Mutation count vary by considerable margin per machine :

```
MutationStage Pool Completed Total:
Overloaded Node: 307531460526
Other Node1: 77979732754
Other Node2: 146376997379
```

Here overloaded node total = ~4x Other Node1 and  ~2x Other Node2. In a well distributed keyspace with MM3 partitioner is this scenario expected?

`nodetool cfstats` output is attached below for reference:

```
Keyspace: cat-48
    Read Count: 122253245
    Read Latency: 1.9288832487759324 ms.
    Write Count: 122243273
    Write Latency: 0.02254735837284069 ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
        Table: bucket_distribution
        SSTable count: 11
        Space used (live): 10149121447
        Space used (total): 10149121447
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 14971512
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.637019014259346
        Number of keys (estimate): 2762585
        Memtable cell count: 255915
        Memtable data size: 19622027
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 487
        Local read count: 122253245
        Local read latency: 2.116 ms
        Local write count: 122243273
        Local write latency: 0.025 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 17
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 9588144
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 9588056
        Index summary off heap memory used: 3545264
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1838192
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 104
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 557074610
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 2145
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 8.83894307680672
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 5722
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
----------------
```

Also I can observe in `nodetool tpstats` that on peak load one node (which is getting overloaded) has pending Native-Transport-Requests:

```
Overloaded Node:
Native-Transport-Requests        32        11      651595401         0               349
MutationStage                    32        41   316508231055         0                 0

The other two:
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0      625706001         0               495
MutationStage                     0         0   151442471377         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0      630331805         0               219
MutationStage                     0         0    78369542703         0                 0
```

I have also checked `nodetool compactionstats` and the output is 0 most of the time, at times when compaction is happen, it is observed that load doesnt increase alarmingly.

Answer (score 0):

Traced it down to issue with Data Model & a Kernel bug which was not patched in the kernel we used. 
Some partitions in the data that we were writing were large that caused imbalance in the write requests, since RF is 1 so One server appeared to be under heavy load.

The kernel issue is described in detail here (in brief it affects java apps which are using park wait): [datastax blog](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/troubleshooting/cassandra/fetuxWaitBug.html)

This is Fixed by [Linux Commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/76835b0ebf8a7fe85beb03c75121419a7dec52f0)